# SQLAlchemy ThreadPoolExecutor "Too many clients"

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I wrote a script with this sort of logic in order to insert many records into a PostgreSQL table as they are generated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as pool
from functools import partial

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


metadata = sa.MetaData(schema='stackoverflow')
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example'
    pk = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = sa.Column(sa.Text)


sa.event.listen(Base.metadata, 'before_create',
    sa.DDL('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS stackoverflow'))

engine = sa.create_engine(
    'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost:5432/stackoverflow'
)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=True)()


def task(value):
    engine.dispose()
    with session.begin():
        session.add(Example(text=value))


async def infinite_task(loop):
    spawn_task = partial(loop.run_in_executor, None, task)
    while True:
        await asyncio.wait([spawn_task(value) for value in range(10000)])


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with pool() as executor:
        loop.set_default_executor(executor)
        asyncio.ensure_future(infinite_task(loop))
        loop.run_forever()
        loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code works just fine, creating a pool of as many processes as I have CPU cores, and happily chugging along forever. I wanted to see how threads would compare to processes, but I could not get a working example. Here are the changes I made:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as pool

session_maker = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=True)
Session = sa.orm.scoped_session(session_maker)


def task(value):
    engine.dispose()
    # create new session per thread
    session = Session()
    with session.begin():
        session.add(Example(text=value))
    # remove session once the work is done
    Session.remove()
```

This version runs for a while before a flood of "too many clients" exceptions:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is `engine.dispose()`, which, in the words of Mike Bayer (zzzeek) "is leaving PG connections lying open to be garbage collected."

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/zhjCBNebnDY

So the updated `task` function looks like this:

```
def task(value):
    # create new session per thread
    session = Session()
    with session.begin():
        session.add(Example(text=value))
    # remove session object once the work is done
    session.remove()
```

Comment: @txomon: it's `Session.remove()`, not `session.remove()` (tried to edit but rejected). The reason is because it's the `sessionmaker` factory instance that has the `remove()` method (you are calling the factory to dereference the current session from the pool; the session is not removing itself). See: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're opening a lot of new connections without closing them, try to add engine.dispose() after:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as pool

session_maker = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=True)
Session = sa.orm.scoped_session(session_maker)


def task(value):
    engine.dispose()
    # create new session per thread
    session = Session()
    with session.begin():
        session.add(Example(text=value))
    # remove session once the work is done
    Session.remove()
    engine.dispose()
```

Keep in mind the cost of a new connection, so ideally you should have one connection per process/thread, but I'm not sure how ThreadPoolExecutor works and probably connections are not being closed on thread's execution finish.

Comment: Unfortunately that extra call of `engine.dispose()` didn't make any difference.

Comment: @user1475412, could your initial version of code with with pool(max_worker=NUMBER_OF_CORES) as executor:`? As I see from documentation, "If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5", so in case of 8 HT cores system, you have 40 threads, but default connections limit in PostgreSQL is 100.

Comment: I reran the code with `pool(max_workers=5)` but ran into the same problem.

Comment: @user1475412, I think that means that your DB engine does not reuse connections from connection pool properly, so my only thought is to use `session.close()` or `session.invalidate()` instead of `Session.remove()` and the row after that.

Comment: see my answer to this... it turns out you were going in the wrong direction! I needed to remove one call to `engine.dispose`, not add one.